# Set default text format for a content type

Tags: nodes

At "Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring"
I added a custom text format (news).

Now when I trie to enable this for a certain content type "Newsmessage"
"Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » Newsmessage » Manage fields"

I only see  "Plain text" or "Filtered text (user selects text format)" as options. 
How do I set the "news" text format as a default for my "newsmessage" content type?

Answer (score 1):

If the field is Wysiwyg, so you might want to configure the "Wysiwyg" profile settings, then it will be available in the Structure » Content types » contentType name  » Manage fields.

Comment: Ye it's available, but I want to set it as a default

Comment: what Wysiwyg module do you use?

Comment: CKeditor____________________

Comment: you can do it this way go to : /admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/ then pick the profile that being used in your field, under basic setup . check the text format that you want to use

Comment: Already done. This adds it to the text format list, but doesn't make it the default (that's what I want)

Comment: Ok, one last thing you could try  go to :/admin/config/content/formats and re-order the text format and make you custom on on the top.

Comment: but then it's going to be on top for all content types, no?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11401/discussion-between-vincent-and-sam2de)

Comment: I don't think it's possible without coding: http://stackroulette.com/drupal/16036/set-a-default-text-format-per-content-type-in-drupal-7

Comment: I'll have a go with Better Formats module

Comment: sorry I have some difficulties on the Pc that I'm using right now, Can't get into chat, I was going to suggest https://drupal.org/project/better_formats to you.. Give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

use the [Better formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_formats) module to do this